# Sabre API Issue Bag Tag

Tags: sabre

We are working on an airline project that requires the use of the issue bag tag (https://developer.sabre.com/docs/sabre_sonic_apis/soap/check_in/issue_bag_tag) service.

This service has the following response:

```
<ns3:IssueBagTagRS xmlns:ns3="http://services.sabre.com/checkin/issueBagTag/v4" xmlns:ns2="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v3">
    <FreeTextInfoList>
        <ns2:FreeTextInfo>
            <ns2:TextLine>
                <ns2:Text>!VS TAGS ISSUED - MINIMUM CLOSE-OUT TIME NOT PRESENT</ns2:Text>
            </ns2:TextLine>
        </ns2:FreeTextInfo>
    </FreeTextInfoList>
    <ItineraryInfoList>
        <FlightInfo>
            <Airline>AZ</Airline>
            <Flight>324</Flight>
            <Origin>FCO</Origin>
            <Destination>CDG</Destination>
        </FlightInfo>
    </ItineraryInfoList>
    <PassengerInfoList>
        <PassengerInfo>
            <LastName>MIKE</LastName>
            <FirstName>HUSSE</FirstName>
            <PassengerID>15D316290001</PassengerID>
            <NumberInParty>1</NumberInParty>
            <Destination>CDG</Destination>
            <CheckInNumber>1</CheckInNumber>
            <BagCount>1</BagCount>
            <BagTagInfoList>
                <BagAdditionalInfo>5055247163V</BagAdditionalInfo>
                <BagTagInfo>
                    <BagTagNumber>5055247163</BagTagNumber>
                    <BagTypeDetailsList>
                        <BagTypeDetail bagTypeCode="V"/>
                    </BagTypeDetailsList>
                </BagTagInfo>
                <TotalWeightAndUnit unit="KG">5</TotalWeightAndUnit>
            </BagTagInfoList>
            <EditCodeList>
                <EditCode>M</EditCode>
            </EditCodeList>
        </PassengerInfo>
    </PassengerInfoList>
    <Result messageId="ID-acs-int1-sgdcelab-sabre-com-42526-1458731313161-2-1016" timeStamp="2016-03-23T13:27:58.132Z">
        <ns2:Status>Success</ns2:Status>
        <ns2:CompletionStatus>Complete</ns2:CompletionStatus>
        <ns2:System>ACS-BSO</ns2:System>
    </Result>
</ns3:IssueBagTagRS>
```

We need to know how we can transform this response into a PECTAB + DATASTREAM, which will allow us to print a BAG TAG.

PECTAB + DATASTREAM example:

PECTAB

```
BTT0201*F 510324=#01C0 5522460302#02C0 5522430302#03C0 5522210302#04B1 E518260532#05C0 5522310302#06C0 E512260201#07C0 5509430201#08C0 5493460201#09C0 1012160201=08#0AC0 5497460201#0BC0 1012070201#0CC0 1312060201#0DC0 5505460201#0EC0 5505360201#0FC0 5505190201#10C0 1318240201#11C0 5501460201=0C#12S0M1384010150#13S0M1346010150#14L0 E491260000#15C0 1306060201=06#19C0 5497260201=10#30B1ME475264041=04#31B1M7425014941=04#32B1 E011260632=04#33B1 E026260632=04#34B1 E041260632=04#35C0 1027070201=0B#36C0 1042070201=0B#37C0 1027160201=08#38C0 1042160201=08#39C0M5432460302=01#3AC0M5432430302=02#3BC0M5432210302=03#3CC0M5432310302=05#3DC0 1002070201=01#3EC0 1002090201=02#3FC0 1002340201=03#40C0 1002210201=05#41C0 1017070201=01#42C0 1017090201=02#43C0 1017340201=03#44C0 1017210201=05#45C0 1032070201=01#46C0 1032090201=02#47C0 1032340201=03#48C0 1032210201=05#49C0 1309060201=01#4AC0 1309080201=02#4BC0 1309210201=03#4CC0 1309150201=05#4DC0 1315060201=07PRINT DATE GMT: #4EC0 1318060201=0A#4FC0 1321060201=08#50C0 B306420403#60C0M5351460301#61C0ME372261812=0D#62C0MM382160703=0E#63C0M5382140201=0F#92C0 F340261207#
```

DATASTREAM

```
BTP020101?010?02999?03999999?040999999999?05OC?060999999999?0722MAR16?08SURNAME0123456/F?0AX2HDUY2?0BBBB?0CDEPARTURECITYNAME012345678901?0DBBB?0EJJ9999A?0F30NOV?10999?1406?509999?60FINALAIRPORTNAME012345678901234?92CREW?
```

Please if someone could solve this issue, I will be attentive to their responses.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Below tag after the "BaggageRouteInfoList" Tag in the Request

`<BagTagPrintingOptions> <GenericBagTag>PECTAB</GenericBagTag> </BagTagPrintingOptions>`